# Log output and error from cron script to custom file with timestamp

Tags: bash, cron

I'm trying to log both stdout and stderr from my cron task to a custom log file. If there is no output or error, I do not want to log anything. If there is either output or error, I want to log it to a new line and prefix it with the current timestamp.

I've tried the following

```
myscript 2>&1 | echo "$(cat -)" | ts >> cron.log
```

This gets me almost what I want. It will log both output and errors from myscript, prefix them with the current timestamp and put them on a new line. The problem is that if myscript produces no output, then because echo produces a new line, I'll get a log entry with just the timestamp on a new line.

I want to do this all on the cron line. I do not want to have to modify `myscript`.

Comment: `myscript 2>&1 | ts >> cron.log`?

Comment: @cyrus unfortunately not. If the script output doesn't end in a new line then everything gets logged to a single line.

Comment: See [bash - How to add a newline to the end of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31947/how-to-add-a-newline-to-the-end-of-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use `sed`:

```
myscript 2>&1 | ts | sed '$a\' >> cron.log
```

*This adds `\n` at the end of the file only if it doesn’t already end with a newline.* -- [l0b0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/31955/74329)